# {New Flutter/Dart programmer} Is there any EASY way to simply access "fields" in Firebase database and set its value to a variable?

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

So I am a brand new programmer, in general, attempting to make an app where I am storing the users changeable name as a field in the Firebase database. It is stored in the following way: Collection (My chat) - Document (LzPiDS8sdf97slDlDFLKJ) <- userID, Field (userPreferredName: 'Dave'). I can't seem to find an easy way to access this parameter. I want to only ever have 1 changeable name per user so I don't think I need streams and all that complex stuff (again I'm new, sorry) to access it. I really just want to set it to a name of my choice (Dave for example, which I know how to do) and then change it (to Phil for example, which I know how to do) and finally make the name-value go into a variable so I can display it in a Text widget which I really don't understand how to do. I want to be able to display it in this variable to display it but I can't seem to make the value of the field ('Dave' per say) go into this variable:

Text(
nameVariable, <- I cannot make this variable easily obtain the name from my field 'userPreferredName'
),

Thanks so much for the help!! I really, really appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I understand your question fully, but this here is how you can query the document you are mentioning:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await Firestore.instance.collection('My chat')
.where('userID', isEqualTo: 'someId')
.getDocuments();
```

this will return a QuerySnapshot, let's assume for a second that there is only 1 corresponding doc:

```
Map<String, dynamic> userData = querySnapshot.documents.first.data;
```

You can then access any field in the userData Map easily.

Comment: I tried your code above and for some reason, it doesn't really work and returns the exception: "Bad state: No element". If we assume for a sec that my collection is called "My Users" and there are multiple documents in it all named after each different user ex. "user1" and inside each document, there are 2 fields: "name" and "email". How exactly would I access the "email" field and set it to the variable "myVariable" exactly? Again sorry for me not fully understanding :) I'm very new. Thanks!